# Flutter W/zipro ( 2568): Error opening archive build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found

Tags: dart, flutter, tic-tac-toe

I built a simple tic tac toe game. At first, when I ran the program on a physical android device, it worked but the day after that it didn't anymore. It shows this error.

> W/zipro   ( 2568): Error opening archive
> build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk:  Invalid file ERROR: dump failed
> because no AndroidManifest.xml found Exit code 1 from:
> C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\28.0.0\aapt dump
> badging build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk

Answer (score 49):

You can use `flutter clean` command. That's worked for me. I hope be useful for you.

Comment: It worked for me but I had to restart Android Studio in order to work.

Answer (score 8):

I tried 'flutter clean' command and 'flutter pub get' command. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Or you can just press the "Run" button. That'll automatically do a `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. run `flutter clean`
2. run `flutter pub get`
3. run `flutter run` or you can use Android studio Run button!

I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `flutter clean` and it worked. Try to run it before running `flutter run`

Answer (score 1):

These 2 steps worked for me:

1. Building an APK; `flutter build apk --release`
2. Run the app: `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

Running `Flutter clean` then `Flutter create .` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete the "build" directory in your flutter  project and then try running the app again.

Answer (score -1):

Delete build file or clear cache as 
flutter clean